# AttributeError: module 'tagulous' has no attribute 'models' in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

So I have been building a web app, and for the tags system, I decided to go with django-tagulous. However, when I import it in my models, I am getting this error:

```py
AttributeError: module 'tagulous' has no attribute 'models' in Django
```

I have put it in my `python INSTALLED_APP` list in settings.py, and imported it in models.py, but still get the error.

Here is some code.

models.py

```py
import tagulous

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_images',blank=True,null=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True,auto_now_add=True)
    NSFW = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    spoiler = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    interests = tagulous.models.TagField()
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

In that Post class, I am using this on the interests one.

Here is my forms.py PostForm

```py
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Post
        fields = ['title','text','image','interests','spoiler','NSFW']
        widgets = {
            'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'textinputclass'}),
            'text':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'textareaclass editable'}),

        }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['image'].required = False
```

So far I have found nothing online about this error. I was expecting it to work, but it didn't
Thanks :)

Comment: Did you by ancy chance define some other module with the name `tagulous`?

Comment: No I haven't. I just checked and can confirm I haven't

Answer (score 1):

Well I continued to look deeper into their documentation and turns out they had a little known import option needed for the models.

Comment: Author of tagulous here - due to import and load order quirks, you need to import `from tagulous.models import TagModel`